# Deleting characters in Broforce

Tags: broforce

I want to get rid of some of the characters in my Broforce game. I was wondering how I do this and where the character config is in the BROFORCE folder.

I am using the free broforce and I don't have it on steam yet.

Comment: Free broforce? Do you mean that you pirated it?

Comment: @ardaozkal Free BroForce exists, as you can see by this link: http://www.broforcegame.com/BROFORCE_BROTOTYPE.html.

Answer (score 2):

`SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Broforce\Saves\Options.xml` doesn't contain any option for this, so I guess it's not (yet) implemented. And since the Steam version is probably the most recent one, it's very likely not available in the free client.